# Why Android Handler 's post method doesn't exist?

Tags: java, android, android-handler

```
guiThread = new Handler()

guiThread.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText(text);
    }
});
```

I am trying learn Android programming from *Hello Android* book written by Ed Burnette. In the book one of the code contains above code. Inside the code I am trying to create a `Handler` object and `post` a new `Runnable` object. But I realize that, in `Handler` class the `post` method doesn't exist. 
Could anyone explain me why I get this error or how can I fix it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Handler does have a post method. Check you imports. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have imported `java.util.logging.Handler`. But you need to import `android.os.Handler` class. Then you will get post method

Comment: @Cagri Candan If you are ok now, please accept his answer.